# How can I create a dictionary between two columns within a pandas dataframe if each column has more than one value per row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe with columns formatted similarly below:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame(
{'A': ['apples|oranges|bananas', 'apples|oranges', 'apples|kiwi'],
 'B': ['store1|store2|store3', 'store1|store2', 'store1|store4']})

A                         B
apples|oranges|bananas    store1|store2|store3
apples|oranges            store1|store2
apples|kiwi               store1|store4
```

The index of each columns separated by "|" is in order. There is no key for which fruit goes with which store other than the current ordering of items per each row in the dataframe. I would like to create a new column with a dictionary for each row that has the desired output:

```
A                         B                     C
apples|oranges|bananas    store1|store2|store3  {store1:apples, store2:oranges, store3:bananas}
apples|oranges            store1|store2         {store1:apples, store2:oranges}
apples|kiwi               store1|store4         {store1:apples, store4:kiwi}
```

First I tried to convert columns A and B to lists and convert them to a dictionary.

```
test_df.A = test_df.A.str.split('|').tolist()
test_df.B = test_df.B.str.split('|').tolist()
```

I have tried a few different methods of converting the lists to a dictionary:

```
test_df['C'] = dict(zip(test_df.A,test_df.B))
```

Does not work and results in a 'TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable' error.

```
test_df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Does not work and results in an 'unhashable type: 'list' error, which I assume is because there are multiple values for the dictionary key in 'B'.

Anything I can do to work through this?

Comment: I would _seriously_ rethink the organization of your data. DataFrames are best-suited for flat data where each cell holds a single simple value. MutliIndices allow you to store more hierarchical data while preserving this flat organization and still allow you to benefit from the performance of pandas.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly need to maintain that organization you can get by with a (slow)  apply where you first split the strings, zip the resulting lists, and make the dict:

```
test_df['C'] = test_df.apply(lambda r: dict(zip(r.B.split('|'), r.A.split('|'))), axis=1)

                        A                     B                                                               C
0  apples|oranges|bananas  store1|store2|store3  {'store1': 'apples', 'store2': 'oranges', 'store3': 'bananas'}
1          apples|oranges         store1|store2                       {'store1': 'apples', 'store2': 'oranges'}
2             apples|kiwi         store1|store4                          {'store1': 'apples', 'store4': 'kiwi'}
```

Because dictionaries must have unique keys, if stores in `B` are ever duplicated on the same line, change `dict` to `tuple` that way you can store everything.

---

However, you can get a similar organization using `explode`. As this results in a flat way to store all of your data, future manipulations will be much easier and more performant. Because we explode the columns, the index is duplicated and allows you to know which row it came from.

```
test_df =  pd.concat([test_df[col].str.split('|').explode() for col in test_df.columns], 1)

         A       B
0   apples  store1
0  oranges  store2
0  bananas  store3
1   apples  store1
1  oranges  store2
2   apples  store1
2     kiwi  store4
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions, I think I understand the importance of explode for storing this data now. Unfortunately with both methods I'm still getting some errors. The first solution gives me a "TypeError: ("'dict' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0') message, and the explode method gives me an "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'.  Is there any reason why this might not be working?

Comment: @Erika the second is likely not working because your version of pandas is too old. It was introduced in 0.24 I think, so it may be worth updating your pandas if you can. The first method is probably not working because you accidentally defined a variable as `dict=` so your overwrote the built in `dict` class. You will need to restart the kernel and make sure you don't name a variable `dict`